# How to properly make an object to follow a path?

Tags: constraints, path

a have a considerably simple path and an object to follow that path. Following the basic procedures:

1. Create a path and object,
2. Add **Follow Path** constraint to the object and select path to follow,
3. Animate the path.

Now I am facing a small issue at **step 2**, adding a path to follow causes object to rotate ambigiously (*at least for me*).

What is the right way to do this? What am I missing?

Here is some screenshots from the scene:

### Before adding constraint

[image]

### Constraint settings

[image]

### After adding constraint

[image]

Comment: Check follow curve and click *Animate Path*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Left follow path without empty
- right follow path with empty

### General steps

1. create a path
2. create an object

   2.1 If you are going to use an empty you can use any,
      usually to avoid complicate things selected **PLANE AXES**
3. select path
4. enter edit mode
5. select a point where you will start to follow the path once selected

   5.1 press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and select cursor to select

   5.2 pres enter or <kbd>LMB</kbd>
6. exit edit mode
7. select the object
8. press SHIFT + S

   8.1 select to Cursor Offset

   8.2 pres enter or <kbd>LMB</kbd>

This is where the road bifurcates into 2, without empty object and with empty object

### follow path without empty

1. select the **OBJECT** that the route will follow (child)
2. select the **PATH** that the route will follow (Parent)
3. press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and select **Follow Path**
4. go to the timeline and press play to get the animation

### follow path with empty

1. select the **OBJECT** that the route will follow (child)
2. select the **EMPTY PLANE AXES** that the route will follow (Parent)
3. select the **EMPTY PLANE AXES** that the route will follow (nao is a child)
4. select the **PATH** that the route will follow (Parent)
5. press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and select **Follow Path**
6. go to the timeline and press play to get the animation

**NOTE:** *for the example with empty change the point of origin of the mesh to the tip of the arrow and in the example without empty the point of origin of the mesh to the tip of the arrow continued in the center of it*

[image: follow Path Example]

### NOTA:

WHEN YOU DO NOT USE THE EMPTY THE OBJECT IS SUFFERED TO DEFORM A LITTLE OR MUCH ACCORDING TO THE ANGLE OF THE CURVES OF THE ROUTE,
when you do not use an empty the mesh that follows the route tends to deform a little or a lot depending on the sharpness of the angles of the curves of the route and usually turns in directions that are not planned

use an empty between the object and the route helps control this and prevents deformation of the mesh

observe the image well and see the detail with both arrows one with empty and one without empty

[image: part 1]
[image: part 2]
[image: part 3]

Comment: Give me a few minutes I will change the work area and I can not delay in the trip, as soon as I get to my office I will finish putting the restriction, if I do not deliver now they will leave me and a storm is approaching and I do not want to get wet; P

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will follow those exact steps and see if it's working. Good luck with the storm btw!

Comment: we are already near the office in about 20 minutes I will put a gif that explains what happens with the restrictions, just let me get there:...

Comment: @firat listo, check the last 3 gif, I think you do not need a written explanation and the graphic explanation will suffice

Comment: if any of this helped you accept the answer that encourages you to follow the effort a bit

Comment: I just changed the **Forwar** axis of constraint to "Z", and **Up** axis to "Y" and checked **Follow Curve" box and it worked. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: vote up please :P or check accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Some points about the *Follow Path* constraint:

- You need to make sure that the curve goes in the direction you want. Select it, go in *Edit* mode, check the normals, if they don't go in the right direction press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Switch Direction*.
- Once you've given the *Follow Path* constraint to your object, its new *000* location is the beginning of the curve. So to put the object at the beginning of the curve, select the object and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.
- If you want your object to be correctly oriented, you might need to select the good *Forward* value in the *Follow Path* constraint. You might also need to rotate your object so that it's well oriented.

There are other things about this constraint, like how to animate it with the *Evaluation Time*, but it's another topic.

Comment: What do you mean by (The origin of the curve at the beginning of the path, if not), what origin?

Comment: My bad, for Follow Path it doesn't matter where the curve origin is   ;)  I've deleted

Comment: The origin of the curve is the point that is seen at the center of the curve or objeo or mesh, what if you must do as you indicate is to place your mesh in the most appropriate position to follow the curve and move in the most appropriate way agree to your vision and desire to obtain the result you are looking for

Comment: Do you know that is origin in blender or do not you know?, I ask this because your answer is not very clear, you do not understand a couple of things that you mentioned, I had to edit your answer a bit to give it shape and even so I was unclear a point about the restriction,

Comment: besides that the object should not be necessarily in the center of the scene as you have commented on your answer, I can put my objects anywhere and tell them to follow the route, or I do not understand your answer is confusing, because I feel that you do not know that is origin or you have a bad definition of the term applied to blender

Comment: put an example with screenshot because I see that you do not know what is origin and I do not understand your explanation, change your edition because in the pop-up menu of W there is no switch option, I want you to show it to me in a screenshot

Comment: plus I think some of your points are not valid or at least not clear at all, why does it mean "select a point where you will start to follow the path once selected"? why do you say "when you do not use an empty the mesh that follows the route tends to deform a little", it's not accurate at all...

Comment: In the user to whom I answered, I solve your problem with my answer, I think the confused person is you, your answer is lousy, final point

Comment: I don't think so, the 2 sentences I quoted make no sense to me, you didn't really address his problem, plus you gave off topic recommendations... anyway...