# Soccer ball not following path

Tags: path

I have a soccer ball of which I want to follow a path. I have entered a bezier curve, entered follow path constraint and yet the ball does not move, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

---

Just to update. I got everything set correctly but the ball still does not move, apologies, but what am I doing wrong

Comment: I give an answer here, maybe it'll help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145024/how-to-properly-make-an-object-to-follow-a-path/145059?noredirect=1#comment247787_145059   if not, please share curve + ball

Comment: Did you click animate path?

Comment: Also note that your modifier appears in red. That means something is wrong in the setup. Here, you can't have up = Y and forward = -Y (or Y). Try up = Z, forward = X or something like that (I usually fiddle with it until it does what I want).

Comment: Yeah I animated path and when I move the keyframes the ball ends up in some other location with a blue line, I dont understand. When I get the correct set up the up and forward, the modifier no longer appears in red. Still cant figure this out

Comment: have you read my answer in the link I've given above?

Comment: yeah I figured it out, I just control P and followed path - so didnt use constraint. How do I have this ath to start at frame 15 and not frame 1?